# Pushing data from input tag into array-php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input

I am working on creating a form and stuck at a point Here is my code in index.php

```
<?php

session_start();
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_SESSION['name'] ) ) {
        echo 'Please Enter  your name to make an entry into database';
        header ( 'location:index.php' );
        //$_SESSION['name'] = [];
        //array_push($_SESSION['name'], $_POST['name']);
    } else {
        array_push( $_SESSION['name'], $_POST['name'] );
        header( 'location:database.php' );
    }
}
?>


<form method="post">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Now in database.php I have the following code

```
 <?php
      session_start();
      if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        $a = $_SESSION['name'];
        print_r($a);
      }
 ?>
```

I don't want to create an array key if input data field is not set (empty) and direct the user to same index page with a message

Comment: You need to save it somehow. You can use sessions, cookies or a database  for it.

Comment: you are creating new array on each submit, so what do you expect?

Comment: Consider "database" rather than "array"

Comment: @ArtOsi how i can overcome with that

Comment: As people mentioned above - use database or session to persist data between requests

Comment: @ArtOsi Edited my question : I have declared global array outside if but getting error

Comment: The php code is executed independent on each request, this means every time you start a request the script has no information of the previous states it had in other requests. This is how the environment works. If you what to share data between requests you need to save that data somewhere. A Database or the session are a good place to start.

Comment: @ArtOsi Used Session but how to add the data into array

Comment: check if session not already exist then create it and push value, else push to existing array, something like `if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = [];
    array_push($_SESSION['name'], $_POST['name']);
} else {
    array_push($_SESSION['name'], $_POST['name']);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding your code it will be:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != '') {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
            $_SESSION['name'] = [];
            array_push($_SESSION['name'], $_POST['name']);
        } else {
            array_push($_SESSION['name'], $_POST['name']);
        }
        header('location:session2.php'); 
    } else {
        $errors = 'Name cannot be empty';
    }

}
?>


<?php if (isset($errors)) : ?>
<span style="color:red"><?= $errors; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<form method="post">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And database.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $a = $_SESSION['name'];
    print_r($a);
}
?>
```

Comment: In the above code, if the input field is empty then also an empty array key is being produced. I want to direct to the same page with the message to User to enter any name if input field is empty (I have updated my question check it now)

Comment: so basically you just want to check if input is not empty??

Comment: yes. If input is empty then it should not create an array key and direct to the same login page with message to enter proper details

Comment: so first check if `$_POST['name']` is set, and if it not add some error message, and display it if error is set. Check the updated code, something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned in the the comments to your question, you have a new array each time. Nothing is being overwritten, because each time you submit, it's a new script. And that's the key: PHP is a scripting language; it's not persistent. Each time you call a PHP script, it runs and dies. Data is not preserved; it is not stateful. Every time you hit submit, it's a brand new call to your server, and the script has NO knowledge of previous runs of the script. Thus, the variable is brand new each time.

That's why everyone is mentioning to use some persistent form of data, be it sessions, cookies, or a database. These methods exist outside of PHP, and allow you to move data between scripts.